# Multiple persistent store coordinator in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I would like to get a clarification on multiple persistent store coordinator in iOS. Does multiple persistent store coordinator mean multiple instance of database? That means different instance of sqlite with different tables in different instance of sqlite database. If that is possible, in what case, we have to implement for an example. Can anyone help to clarify this to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation:

> A persistent store coordinator associates persistent object stores and a managed object model

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/Art/advanced_persistent_stack.jpg

**In plain English, for the reasonable man, with some simplification:**

- The Managed Object Model describes what the entities are, and what relationships they have, if any, with respect to each other. The MOM is, in essence, a static resource.
- The Managed Object Context is a link in a chain, with the root being a Persistent Store Coordinator. A Managed Object Context maintains the state of entities, typically in memory. When an operation on such objects is completed, you save such MOC, typically down to the Persistent Store Coordinator. Applications can have concurrent MOC, one for the UX thread, and one or more for background threads, such as sync.
- The Persistent Store Coordinator talks to the Persistent Store or Persistent Stores on one end, and the MOCs on the other. While it is clever and even advised to create MOC at will, so that objects can be manipulated freely, you only want a single PSC per DB.
- The Persistent Object Store is your interface to the DB. One per DB.

**For the layman:**

- **MOM**: only 1 (ignoring DB upgrades and such complications)
- **MOC**: one per thread. Simple apps *may* get away with a single UX one, but beware of lengthy operations.
- **PSC**: one per MOM
- **POS**: at least one